# Is there anyway to disable only certain plugins if they exist with an mu-plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am currently doing this and want to first check if those plugins exist. Unfortunately, from what I cans see, mu-plugins load before normal plugins are loaded so I cannot get the plugins as I normally would. Is there anyway to do this?

```
<?php
add_filter('pre_option_active_plugins', 'default_plugins');
add_filter('pre_site_option_active_sitewide_plugins', 'default_plugins');

function default_plugins() {

<-- add logic to get list of plugins on site -->

    return array(
    "plugin1",
    "plugin2",
    "plugin3",
  );
}
```